# URL rewrite http to https not working for WCF web application in IIS

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting

I have added URL rewrite for Http to Https for website. But website has many web applications and URL rewriting is not working for web applications. It is showing 404 error

followed this url for http tp https https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/

added rule to default website. but rule not working for web applications. How to apply rule to web applications too?

https://www.xyz1.com has url. I can see rule on web.config

https://www.xyz1.com/subsite/Testweb.svc - not working. rule not found in web.config

Comment: Try to not use terms like `subsite` in the future when discussing IIS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis as IIS doesn't have that concept at all. What exactly is the rewrite rule you configured? Site level rewrite rules are inherited by child elements (applications/virtual directories) so they should work just the way you want.

Comment: I suggest you use failed request tracking to view detailed request information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.